# In Apostol's Calculus volume I, what does he mean by 'sums are uniquely determined' in the proof for cancellation law for addition?

Tags: real-analysis

Apostol writes, Given a+b=a+c. Now there exists a real number y, such that, a+y=0.
Then he says, "Since sums are uniquely determined, we have y+(a+b) = y+(a+c)."

What does this mean?

[**Before mentioning the field axioms, he does say "It is assumed that the sum x+y and the product xy are uniquely determined by x and y"]

Answer (score 2):

A sum is "uniquely determined" if it always the same when the same two numbers are added. More formally, if $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$ then $a_1+b_1=a_2+b_2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've got it. But in order to have a better understanding of the axioms, definitions and the other 'foundational assumptions', is the relation which you wrote some kinda definition( or a property deduced from the definition of the equality relation)? Cuz Apostol starts from the field axioms... doesn't make no mention of the equality relation or its properties.

Comment: PS: I'm a beginner in Real Analysis, just wanted to have a more rigorous understanding of the topic 

Comment: Actually my first statement is probably more "foundational" than the second. The issue is what "the same" means. In this question "the same" means equality. The second form is not so much part of a definition of equality as part of a definition of addition. It might also be expressed in some way like "the sum of two numbers $a$ and $b$ is a function of the two numbers". However, in English usage "the sum of two numbers $a$ and $b$" means that there is exactly one such sum, so just using that expression asks us to make that assumption.

Answer (score -2):

He probably wants to prove the cancelation law here, if I'm not mistaken.
As you said, by the field axioms, the additive inverse exists, which means you can find a real number  "y" such that $a + y=0$. We have assumed that $a+b=a+c$, and we want to get rid of "a" here. The first thing that comes to mind is adding $y$ to both sides of the equation. Are we allowed to do that? Well, since both sides are equal, and adding the same number to both sides only gives one unique number, as he mentioned "Since sums are uniquely determined", we are allowed to do so. Therefore, $y+(a+b) = y+(a+c)$. By associativity, $(y+a)+b= (y+a)+c \implies 0+b=0+c \implies b=c$

Comment: Yes he does want to prove the cancellation law. Thanks for the answer.